# How do I make a QR code for an ethereum address?

Tags: addresses

I am not super familiar with QR codes.

Is there a piece of open source software I can use o convert an address to a QR code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to generate ethereum paper wallets?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103/is-there-a-way-to-generate-ethereum-paper-wallets)

Comment: Not a duplicate; QR codes have plenty of use cases outside paper wallets.

Comment: I think I'm conflating "paper wallets" with "QR code". I imagine there are other forms of paper wallets which *aren't* QR codes. Duplicate removed.

Comment: In what context? Do you want to make you app or site display QR code or do you just need it for your own use one time?

Comment: It looks like myetherwallet is producing invalid codes. It should be ethereum:x0... I'm not sure what they are putting in their codes, but it's non standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=0x8CCF9C4a7674D5784831b5E1237d9eC9Dddf9d7F&choe=UTF-8

Where:

- chs=300x300 = size
- cht=qr = type
- chl=0x8CCF9C4a7674D5784831b5E1237d9eC9Dddf9d7F = eth address
- choe=UTF-8 = encoding

Comment: Some people recommend prefixing this with a scheme

Comment: @FullDecent Not sure what you mean, so you have any reference for your comment?

Comment: The api is now deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest way would be to copy your ETH address and paste it in the text field of this website.. http://www.qr-code-generator.com/

Answer (score 3):

With the oficial Ethereum Wallet software you can do it, just need to go to the account and in the right side of the interfice view you have this option => **"Show QR-code"** click here and the program show you in the screen the QR code for this direccion account.

[image: Here the example]

Answer (score 2):

You can go to https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info and select 'View with Address Only', paste any address, and it'll spit out a QR code (along with some other info)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Javascript you can use [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode) (in nodejs or in browser)

Example :

```
<script src="node_modules/qrcode/build/qrcode.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="qrcodec"></canvas>


<script>
 qrcodelib.toCanvas(document.getElementById('qrcodec'), "your eth address", function (error) {
    if (error) console.error(error)
    console.log('qrcode successfully created');
  });


</script>
```

alternatively you can use this related module dedicated to Ethereum :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-qr-code

Answer (score 1):

you can do it easily in tolls like [ethereum qr code generator](https://bitcoinqrcodegenerator.win/ethereum.html). For btc and eth for example here https://bitcoinqrcodegenerator.win/ethereum.html