# Move/Sell ether from Etherscan to another wallet

Tags: ether, etherscan

I bought some ether at bitpanda.com and pasted it into my watchlist at etherscan.io. Now I have some questions:

1. Can I sell my actual ETH at etherscan?
2. If not, how can I move it to my wallet at coinbase/Ethereum wallet app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

About your first question: Etherscan is a search engine, not an exchange. You cannot sell ETH there, only look things up.

About your second question: What Ethereum address did you give when you purchased from Bitpanda? Normally, that's when you would have entered your Ethereum wallet address at Coinbase. [Here is a short primer on how this typically works](https://thecryptoproezine.com/2017/05/27/how-to-purchase-ethereum-via-bitpanda/). By the way if you are using Coinbase for storage, you might want to read [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-safely-store-ether) and [that post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16971/how-can-i-locally-store-my-ether-from-coinbase) about how to safely store your Ethers.